# How to make LibGDX Desktop go fullscreen by default

Tags: java, libgdx, fullscreen, desktop

I was wondering how to make my desktop app go fullscreen upon start-up. I am new to LibGDX and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just define `fullscreen` field in your `LwjglApplicationConfiguration`:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

cfg.title = "yourGame";
cfg.width = 1024;
cfg.height = 768;
cfg.fullscreen = true;

new LwjglApplication(new ...(), cfg);
```

Comment: In Windows 10 it does not work, it shows a small window.

Comment: @LimThyeChean, works in 1.6.0 for Windows 10 as well.

Comment: I am using 1.6.4, and this does not work on my Windows 10. Using this works: config.width = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().width;
config.height = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().height;

Comment: Thanks Lim Thye Chean, It works in my windows 8.1 also

Comment: This works, but it's useless without knowing native screen resolution. Why should I fix screen resolution to 1024 x 678 if somebody is using FHD screen? How can I get native screen resolution at that point?

Comment: Why did you specify a width and height when the desktop is fullscreen?

Comment: @ShikharMainalee you actually have to specify resolution even in the fullscreen mode, so you can get more or less detail. You obviously cannot specify more than your display can provide, but you can specify less, so you'll get less resolution but gain in performance.

Answer (score 7):

To start your game with fullscreen mode set the following flags in LwjglApplicationConfiguration in your Desktop launcher (the main() function)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.width = 1280;
    cfg.height = 720;

    // fullscreen
    cfg.fullscreen = true;
    // vSync
    cfg.vSyncEnabled = true;

    new LwjglApplication(new YourApplicationListener(), cfg);
}
```

And if you want to enable full screen at any resolution or the desktop's default from an in-game option use

```
// set resolution to HD ready (1280 x 720) and set full-screen to true
Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(1280, 720, true);

// set resolution to default and set full-screen to true
Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(
              Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width,
              Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height, 
              true
);
```

Comment: Sadly, `setDisplayMode` method isn't available anymore.

Comment: So what is the alternative now? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Now there is [setFullScreenMode(Graphics.DisplayMode displayMode)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#setFullscreenMode-com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.DisplayMode-)

Answer (score 2):

To set the game to full screen when the user presses <kbd>F</kbd>, and set to windowed on <kbd>G</kbd> (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
    override fun render() {
        ...
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.F))
            Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.displayMode)
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.G))
            Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(1280, 720)
        ...
    }
```

I'll change my answer to Java later and I'll add a way to toggle it.

Comment: This somehow makes `isCursorCatched = true` stop working for me... sigh, oh libGDX