# Libgdx Unscaled Fullscreen

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine, fullscreen

I'm using libgdx for a PC game. I am trying to make the window fullscreen while keep the original window size (1024 x 768). In other word, I want to preserve my 1024 x 768, have the game centered at the middle of the screen, and just have the black background filled in the surrounding. (I don't want my game automatically scale to the size of the host computer screen's height and width.)

I've tried with this solution. But the window is scaled and that's not exactly what I want. =(
[How to make LibGDX Desktop go fullscreen by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784482/how-to-make-libgdx-desktop-go-fullscreen-by-default)

Is it achievable in Libgdx? Thank you very much for any clue! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). In your case what you need is to use [ScalingViewport](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/ScalingViewport.html) and initialize it with `Scaling.none` parameter. I.e.:

```
myStaticViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, 1024, 768);
```

This exact example is mentioned [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#customviewport).